# Почему автор статьи использует дробь если должны быть целые числа?

Tags: дискретная-математика

Автор в этой [статье](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Nina_Rizun/publication/258226682_Using_the_Theory_of_Fuzzy_Set_for_Identifying_Degree_of_Theme_Complexity_in_Computer_Knowledge_Testing_Systems/links/0c960527794a68cef1000000/Using-the-Theory-of-Fuzzy-Set-for-Identifying-Degree-of-Theme-Complexity-in-Computer-Knowledge-Testing-Systems.pdf) описывает метод инициализации сложности темы. Вот здесь (ниже на скрине)

[image]

он говорит что определят уровень преимущества одной темы над другой с помощью шкалы Саати (цифры от 1 до 9). Но затем приводя таблицу сравнений он использует дробь. Может кто понял почему???

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Просто с позиций банальной логики. Обратите внимание - эта шкала определяет баллы только для темы, имеющей преимущество. Но второй теме, той, которая уступает, тоже надо какую-то оценку присвоить. Вот автор и использует значение, обратное к тому, которое присвоено статье, имеющей преимущество.

Comment: Спасибо, вы правы)